# How do I get around the 64 max levels of nesting in Excel?

Tags: excel

Here is an example of what I need.. I have well over several thousand IF statements that I need to use..but Microsoft decided to give Excel a limit of 64 nests. (as to why, I do not understand.)(it doesn;t get hard to read or debug..that;s what I do best).

> =IF(A3="1/2in. E.M.T. Conduit",'Master Items Price List'!G5,IF(A3="3/4in. E.M.T. Conduit",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G6,IF(A3="1in. E.M.T. Conduit",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G7,IF(A3="1 1/4in. E.M.T. Conduit",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G8,IF(A3="1 1/2in. E.M.T. Conduit",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G9,IF(A3="2in. E.M.T. Conduit",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G10,IF(A3="2 1/2in. E.M.T. Conduit",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G11,IF(A3="3in. E.M.T. Conduit",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G12,IF(A3="3 1/2in. E.M.T. Conduit",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G13,IF(A3="4in. E.M.T. Conduit",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G14,IF(A3="1/2in. Aluminum Conduit",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G17,IF(A3="3/4in. Aluminum Conduit",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G18,IF(A3="1in. Aluminum Conduit",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G19,IF(A3="1 1/4in. Aluminum Conduit",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G20,IF(A3="1 1/2in. Aluminum Conduit",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G21,IF(A3="2in. Aluminum Conduit",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G22,IF(A3="2 1/2in. Aluminum Conduit",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G23,IF(A3="3in. Aluminum Conduit",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G24,IF(A3="3 1/2in. Aluminum Conduit",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G25,IF(A3="4in. Aluminum Conduit",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G26,IF(A3="1/2in. RMC",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G29,IF(A3="3/4in. RMC",'Master Items Price List'!G30,IF(A3="1in.
>   RMC",'Master Items Price List'!G31,IF(A3="1 1/4in. RMC",'Master Items
>   Price List'!G32,IF(A3="1 1/2in. RMC",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G33,IF(A3="2in. RMC",'Master Items Price List'!G34,IF(A3="2
>   1/2in. RMC",'Master Items Price List'!G35,IF(A3="3in. RMC",'Master
>   Items Price List'!G36,IF(A3="3 1/2in. RMC",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G37,IF(A3="4in. RMC",'Master Items Price List'!G38,IF(A3="1/2in.
>   IMC",'Master Items Price List'!G41,IF(A3="3/4in. IMC",'Master Items
>   Price List'!G42,IF(A3="1in. IMC",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G43,IF(A3="1 1/4in. IMC",'Master Items Price List'!G44,IF(A3="1
>   1/2in. IMC",'Master Items Price List'!G45,IF(A3="2in. IMC",'Master
>   Items Price List'!G46,IF(A3="2 1/2in. IMC",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G47,IF(A3="3in. IMC",'Master Items Price List'!G48,IF(A3="3
>   1/2in. IMC",'Master Items Price List'!G49,IF(A3="4in. IMC",'Master
>   Items Price List'!G50,IF(A3="1/2in. PVC",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G53,IF(A3="3/4in. PVC",'Master Items Price List'!G54,IF(A3="1in.
>   PVC",'Master Items Price List'!G55,IF(A3="1 1/4in. PVC",'Master Items
>   Price List'!G56,IF(A3="1 1/2in. PVC",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G57,IF(A3="2in. PVC",'Master Items Price List'!G58,IF(A3="2
>   1/2in. PVC",'Master Items Price List'!G59,IF(A3="3in. PVC",'Master
>   Items Price List'!G60,IF(A3="3 1/2in. PVC",'Master Items Price
>   List'!G61,IF(A3="4in. PVC",'Master Items Price List'!G62,IF(A3="1/2in.
>   Aluminum 45",'Master Items Price List'!N17,IF(A3="3/4in. Aluminum
>   45",'Master Items Price List'!N18,IF(A3="1in. Aluminum 45",'Master
>   Items Price List'!N19,IF(A3="1 1/4in. Aluminum 45",'Master Items Price
>   List'!N20,IF(A3="1 1/2in. Aluminum 45",'Master Items Price
>   List'!N21,IF(A3="2in. Aluminum 45",'Master Items Price
>   List'!N22,IF(A3="2 1/2in. Aluminum 45",'Master Items Price
>   List'!N23,IF(A3="3in. Aluminum 45",'Master Items Price
>   List'!N24,IF(A3="3 1/2in. Aluminum 45",'Master Items Price
>   List'!N25,IF(A3="4in. Aluminum 45",'Master Items Price
>   List'!N26,IF(A3="1/2in. Aluminum 90",'Master Items Price
>   List'!U17,IF(A3="3/4in. Aluminum 90",'Master Items Price
>   List'!U18,IF(A3="1in. Aluminum 90",'Master Items Price
>   List'!U19,IF(A3="1 1/4in. Aluminum 90",'Master Items Price
>   List'!U20,IF(A3="1 1/2in. Aluminum 90",'Master Items Price
>   List'!U21,"Check The
>   Description!")))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

Basically, I am taking cell C3 and creating a program which will allow me to input any "Name" into cell A3 and linking that name with a price from a different sheet. (the "Master Items Price List Sheet")

Can anyone help me out?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/alternatives_to_nested_if_functions/

Comment: Dear lord my eyes are bleeding! Seriously though, perhaps split it up into multiple formulae and put each section in it's own column (perhaps hiding it)

Comment: @pnuts Could you give me an example of one? I've done research but I learn quicker if I'm working together with someone.

Answer (score 0):

You need a vLookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,<The range of cells in 'Master Items Price List' Starting with the values that appear in A3', The column number in the range of cells you chose with the prices, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

A price array, here shown on the same sheet but if a named range (here `Larray`) of Workbook scope can be elsewhere, simplified as F2:G4, with `G57` etc representing the price actually in that cell 
in `Master Items Price List` - provided it matches the F value for that row:

[image: SO25995227 example]

The formula in C3 is:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,Larray,2,0)
```

and the result should depend upon what is entered into A3 (but must match exactly).

Because of the match, either use data validation on A3 or create A3 by concatenating a measure (eg `2-1/2"` with a type eg `PVC` - possible with each of these selected via Data Validation.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a single two column Price list with the description in the first column and the price in the next then you can use a simple VLOOKUP function.

For example list all descriptions in Y2:Y100 and corresponding prices in Z2:Z100 then use this formula

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,Y$2:Z$100,2,0),"Check the description")`